# Insert a row after a specific text - VBA

Tags: vba

I want to insert a row in a excel spreadsheet after a specific text is found is a column. The text appears N times and the new row need to be inserted after the last time the text appears.

An example of what I have

```
ColumnA
TextA
TextA
TextA
TextA
TextB
TextB
TextB
TextB
TextC
TextC
TextC
TextC
```

I need to insert a new row after the last time `TextA`, `TextB` and `TextC` appear, each time I execute the macro.

Is there a way to find the maximum number of times a given text appears in a column? In that way it will be possible to do what I want.

**EDIT:**

I have tried to count the number of times each text appears and assign this value to a variable:

```
Sub count()
Dim A As Integer
A = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "TextA")

Dim B As Integer
B = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "TextB")

Dim C As Integer
C = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "TextC")
End Sub
```

After that I tried to insert a new row

```
Sub insert_row ()
    Rows("4+A:4+A").Select 'The number 4 is the first row `TextA` appears. So 4+A where I need to insert my new row.
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

With this code I have to problems

1 - A have much more than just `TextA`, `TextB` and `TextC` texts to find. Actually I have 30 different texts in the column.

2 - Sub insert_row () does not work.

Comment: I'm a little bit rusty in VBA, but let me see what can I do?

Comment: @Rods, have you tried any code of your own? Can you show us what  you tried?

Comment: @Miguel I just edited showing what I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loops through the cells and adds a row each time a cell is not equal to the cell below it and the cell is not blank.

```
 Sub Insert()
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim Cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row

    For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
        If Cell.Value <> Cell.Offset(1, 0) Then
            If Cell.Value <> "" Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Cell.Row + 1).Insert
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: I have Sheet1 in the LastRow formula, but this can be changed to any sheet you are working on.

Comment: I changed "Sheet1" to the sheet I'm working on and tried to execute the code. It gives me an error saying that Sub or function is not defined. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: Sorry it should be Sheets Not Sheet before ("Sheet1")

Comment: Just edited and executed the code. It never stops e nothing happens to the spreadsheet I am working on

Comment: Interesting it works on my test spreadsheet, did you try with my latest edit

Comment: I have forgotten to change "Sheet1" to the name of the sheet I'm working on in one line of code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It did everything correctly except for one point. It inserted a new line after the column names, what I didn't want. Do you know how to fix it? I'm really nube at VBA

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents, if performance is of any value to you.

> The following code requires that you go into the VBE's Tools ► References and add Microsoft Scripting Runtime. This holds the library definitions for a Scripting.Dictionary. However, if you use CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"), you do not require the library reference.

[image]

with this code you use a scripting dictionary to find the distinct values in column A then you find the last time that value was used and insert a row right below.

```
Sub findlastItem()

Dim unique As Object
Dim firstcol As Variant

Set unique = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 
With Worksheets("sheet1")
 
 firstcol = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
 
 For v = LBound(firstcol, 1) To UBound(firstcol, 1)
 If Not unique.Exists(firstcol(v, 1)) Then _
                unique.Add Key:=firstcol(v, 1), Item:=vbNullString
      Next v
  End With
 
  For Each myitem In unique
     findAndInsertRow myitem
  Next

 End Sub


Sub findAndInsertRow(findwhat As Variant)

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LastRange As Range
    
    listOfValues = Array(findwhat)

    If Trim(findwhat) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")

                Set Rng = .Find(What:=listOfValues(i), _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Rng.Offset(1, 0).Insert
                 End If
            
        End With
    End If
```