# How to store variable collections in a dictionary with VBA

Tags: vba, dictionary, collections

This problem has been bothering me for a few days now and I think it's time I reach our for some help (before I go crazy)!

I have a loop that is creating a billing history for clients and toward the end of the loop I want to store (globally) a dictionary of their billing history per account, per client. The catch is that I don't know how many accounts the client has and I don't know the number of billing months each account has. I have counters set up in my loop to determine this and have arrived at this point.

this seems to work correctly, but I can't figure out how to pull the info out?
For example, I want the first month's history from account 1....or I want all history from account 3..?

See below for samples of my code and thanks for any help!

So, I'm trying to do this:

In my loop:

```
        'GET HISTORY
        Set cBilling = GetBillingHistory(billCounter)

        cAllBillHistory.Add accountnumber, cBilling
```

The function that supports this is:

```
Function GetBillingHistory(billCounter As Integer) As Object

Set GetBillingHistory = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sess0.Screen

    For x = 1 To billCounter
        Set coll = New collection
        coll.Add .GetString(9, 71, 7) 'BILL TOTAL
        coll.Add .GetString(12, 70, 7) 'CURR DUE
        coll.Add .GetString(7, 15, 8) 'PROC DATE
        coll.Add .GetString(12, 14, 8) 'STATUS
        coll.Add .GetString(10, 12, 7) 'SUBSIDY

        GetBillingHistory.Add ("dict" & x), coll

        .SendKeys ("<PF4>")
        Do Until Sess0.Screen.OIA.XStatus <> 5
        Loop
    Next
end with
end function
```

Comment: Hey JP1 thanks for posting the code. Is this  building an array from the cells in excel? in this question I answered with a scripting dictionary and then loop through it. Let me know if it helps or if it doesn't I can help you arrive at your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141132/insert-a-row-after-a-specific-text-vba/43144453#43144453

Comment: Why not also make the collection into a dictionary and then you can access the items via the keys.

Comment: Is the problem you are having one of being unable to create a dictionary of dictionaries of collections or one of having difficulty using it once created? The entire approach looks on the baroque side, I suspect that there must be a simpler way.

Comment: Or you could write the data to a spreadsheet in table format and then use sql to get the data you need.

Comment: @Miguel - No, this is all on a userform. Thanks!